# Set default image for user before changing profile picture in firebase + Vue + Quasar

Tags: vuejs2, firebase-storage, vuex

I'm working on a school Application where Student, Staff and non-Staff can access, how can i add a functionality in the img src that gives users a default profile picture, so every new user i create, won't have a blank img src.

My Template looks like this:

```
<q-avatar size="150px" class="q-mb-sm">
  <q-img :loading="loading" :src="userDetails.image" />
</q-avatar>
```

My State

```
email:"opeyemi@gmail.com"
image:undefined
name:"Opeyemi"
select:"Student"
userId:"4arS2LtESXb9u5uRjXcJl9u9prP2"
```

Of course the image will return undefined, how can i commit a default profile picture for new users

How i register my Users

```
registerUsers({}, payload) {
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
      .then(res => {
        const userId = res.user.uid;
        console.log(res)
        Notify.create({
          message: 'Regsitration Successful!.',
          color: 'positive',
          classes: 'quick'
        })
        //set user
        firebaseDb.ref(`users/${userId}`).set({
          name: payload.name,
          email: payload.email,
          select: payload.select
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        Notify.create({
          message: `${err.message}`,
          classes: 'quick',
          color: 'negative'
        })
      })

    console.log(payload)
```

Comment: Need to see more code, how is `registerUsers` called?

Comment: through ...mapActions in the component, i solved it tho, by using quasar placeholder prop for the image, so every new users get the placeholder image before setting a profile picture.